# How to force implied PowerShell Format-Table to repeat headers for repeated output?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I am trying to repeat *nix `watch` functionality as provided by [johnrizzo1](https://superuser.com/users/332870/johnrizzo1) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/191063/what-is-the-windows-analog-of-the-linux-watch-command).

```
function Watch {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [int]$n = 10,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$command
    )
    process {
        $cmd = [scriptblock]::Create($command);
        While($True) {
            Clear-Host;
            Write-Host "Command: " $command;
            $cmd.Invoke();
            sleep $n;
        }
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -function Watch

watch -n 1 '$PSVersionTable.PSVersion'
```

The problem is that only 1st run displays headers. After that is looks ugly as headers are being stripped from output:

```
Command:  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion                                     
5      0      10586  117
```

By the way all other PS solutions to `watch` in the link above suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work now, but your output is forced to be piped to Format-Table so it will always be in Table format.

```
function Watch {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [int]$n = 10,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$command
    )
    process {
        $cmd = [scriptblock]::Create($command)
        While($True) {
            Clear-Host
            Write-Host "Command: " $command
            $cmd.Invoke() | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders:$false
            sleep $n
        }
    }
}

watch -n 1 '$PSVersionTable.PSVersion'
```

Comment: This works for ad-hoc command where I can add explicit Format-Table. This does not work with generic command.

Comment: So the table headers are written once and then you're clearing the screen to do something PowerShell isn't really made for.

Comment: Have fun with that

Comment: OK, my bad, you were right. Piped `ft` do not hurt, your solution works for any command and output.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this has other issues but simply changing

```
$cmd.invoke();
```

to

```
$cmd.invoke() | ft;
```

works for me

Comment: So there should be `ft` either inside ScriptBlock (as Shawn Esterman suggested) or in the `watch` code. This solution is acceptable but does not look nice for me.

Comment: Shawn changed his answer to the same as this one. He should re-add his original solution to his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - Pipe the command via the Format-Table -RepeatHeader parameter.

```
$cmd.Invoke() | Format-Table -RepeatHeader:$true
```

For my issue, I was clearing the screen between each PS command, Powershell would only present the table headers on the first run. The Format-Table -RepeatHeader Parameter is designed for when output fills an entire page and to re-present the table headers on each page. For my purposes, it worked when re-running same command in same script block after a Clear-Host command

```
function Watch {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,ConfirmImpact='High')]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
               ValueFromPipeline=$True,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [int]$n = 10,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
               ValueFromPipeline=$True,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$command
)
process {
    $cmd = [scriptblock]::Create($command)
    While($True) {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "Command: " $command
        $cmd.Invoke() | Format-Table -RepeatHeader:$true
        sleep $n
    }
}
```

}

watch -n 1 '$PSVersionTable.PSVersion'